# Executing a Telnet command in an ssh command

Tags: windows, unix, hp-ux

I want have a Telnet command inside the ssh command for executing the Telnet command at the remote machine (`172.202.230.22`). I tried with the command

```
ssh Administrator@172.202.230.22 telnet 10.86.114.10 8088
```

It is giving an error message like

> command not found (error code:127),

But when I tried to execute the same Telnet command directly at `172.202.230.22` it is executing fine. What is the reason?

Comment: Which ssh server are you running on 172.202.230.22?

Comment: It looks like you are Cygwin. Are you trying to invoke the windows version of telnet or the cygwin version (I assume there must be one).

Answer (score 5):

Specify the full path to `telnet`:

```
$ ssh Administrator@172.202.230.22 /usr/bin/telnet 10.86.114.10 8088
```

Comment: also try nesting the command in single or double quotes, as I think ssh parses the arguments in a space separated list.

Comment: Putting the command into quotes is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for you response and i tried with the above specified two methods but still it is not working... :(

Comment: What did you get?

Comment: even is it not atall giving any error message it is just simply comming to command prompt with %errorlevel% =-1

Answer (score 1):

Because of you are connecting as `Administrator` user, so I think 172.202.230.22 is a Windows server.

Make sure that you have `C:\WINDOWS\system32` in your PATH:

```
$ ssh Administrator@172.202.230.22 path
PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
```

If not, try to use the full path to the `telnet.exe`:

```
$ ssh Administrator@172.202.230.22 '"C:\WINDOWS\system32\telnet.exe" 10.86.114.10 8088'
```